# get matching array element from document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assuming I have this documents in mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
    "myList" : [
        {
            "a" : true,
            "b" : mydata1
        },
        {
            "a" : true
            "b" : mydata2
        },
        {
            "a" : false
            "b" : mydata3
        },
        {
            "a" : false
            "b" : mydata4
        },
        {
            "a" : true
            "b" : mydata5
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all array cells that have "*a:true*" in them.

I tried mongodb find(), but it only return single first match, which is a problem.

I ended up using *$filter* because I do not want to use *$unwind* (performance issues).

trying to execute this line, doesn't work:

```
.aggregate([
{$match: {_id: NUUID("d75dcc8d-ecb2-4d23-99d5-347bc99cfeec")}}, 
{$project:
    {
        myList: 
        {
            $filter: {
                input: '$myList',
                as: 'myElement',
                cond: {$eq: [{'$$myElement.a': true}]}
        }}
    }
 }
 ])
```

But this doesn't seems to work, it says that $$ is not recognized.
I wander what am I missing and also, why can't find() be used? it sound so basic to ask for some elements in array using a project.

Comment: NUUID does not exist, what r u talking about? `UUID(<string>)` instead works fine. Also `$eq:[{"$$a":"b"}]` should be `$eq:[{"$$a","b"}]` with a comma between the things you compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me is working (sharded cluster version 4.4.3):

```
mongos> db.e.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"), "myList" : [ { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata1" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata2" }, { "a" : false, "b" : "mydata3" }, { "a" : false, "b" : "mydata4" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata5" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a8"), "myList" : [ { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata1" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata2" }, { "a" : false, "b" : "mydata3" }, { "a" : false, "b" : "mydata4" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata5" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata6" } ] }

mongos> db.e.aggregate({$project: { myList: { $filter:{  input:"$myList" , as:"element" , cond: {$eq:[ "$$element.a",true  ] }               }   }         }})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"), "myList" : [ { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata1" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata2" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata5" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a8"), "myList" : [ { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata1" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata2" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata5" }, { "a" : true, "b" : "mydata6" } ] }
mongos>
```

Comment: I used robomongo for nuuid conversion, but that doesn't relate to the question, in any case the equaliy was the issue thanks for the example kiko075